# 2 WEBVIEW в одной активити, как использовать разные cookie?

Tags: android, android-webview

Есть в моём браузере два webview.
Я хочу зайти с первого webview в один аккаунт на сайте, а с другого под другим.
Но сейчас если я захожу в первом webview на аккаунт №1, то в cookie записываеться этот аккаунт и он открываеться во втором webview.
Что делать?